# Ruby: find left truncatable primes between 10 to 9999(efficiently)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, primes

As the title says. I want to find all left truncatable primes between 10 and 9999 using Ruby language.
Following is what I tried and it gives me the result.

```
require 'prime'
require 'benchmark'

trunc_primes = []

Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report{
    Prime.each(10000).each do |num|
      is_tunc_prime = true
      (1..(num.to_s.length)).to_a.reverse.each do |i|
        factor = 10 ** i
        unless num.divmod(factor)[1].prime?
          is_tunc_prime = false
          break
        end
      end
      trunc_primes << num if is_tunc_prime
    end;nil
  }
end
```

Question:
Can this script be optimized further(lesser loops, use formula rather than factor division technique) ?

---

Benchmark stats:

```
➜  truncatable git:(master) ✗ ruby truncatable_primes.rb
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000026)
--------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000020)
➜  truncatable git:(master) ✗ ruby truncatable_primes.rb
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000024)
--------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000017)
➜  truncatable git:(master) ✗ ruby truncatable_primes.rb
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000028)
--------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000044)
➜  truncatable git:(master) ✗ ruby truncatable_primes.rb
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000030)
--------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000019)
```

---

Benchmark above script and [Amadan's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35079767/1125893)

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
mine     0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.022804)
Amadan   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001559)
--------------------------------- total: 0.020000sec

           user     system      total        real
mine     0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.019625)
Amadan   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001540)
```

Comment: I don't think the code actually works as you specified mm.

Comment: It works per the definition of [Truncatable prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime). In this case I am only validating **left truncatable prime** and pushing them in trunc_primes.

Comment: Please justify down votes. It would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: You are asking about optimizing code that doesn't even work, and when it is pointed out to you that the code doesn't work, instead of fixing the broken code, you just proclaim that it does, thus indirectly calling the people who helpfully pointed out to you multiple times that your code is broken liars. While downvotes *should* be based on the quality of the content and not on personal traits of the author, the fact that the question doesn't make sense (asking about optimizing code that gives wrong results) definitely *does* warrant downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're already using `Prime`, why invent hot water?

```
Prime.each(10000).reject { |p| p < 10 }.select { |p|
  s = p.to_s
  1.upto(s.length - 1).all? { |i|
    s[i] != '0' && Prime.prime?(s[i .. -1].to_i)
  }
}
```

EDIT: This can actually be optimised further though - if `ABCD` turns out not to be a truncatable prime, `ZABCD` does not need to be tested:

```
require 'set'
require 'prime'
Set.new.tap { |f|
  Prime.each(10000) { |p|
    s = p.to_s
    f << p if p < 10 || (s[1] != '0' && f.include?(s[1 .. -1].to_i))
  }
}.reject { |p| p < 10 }
```

EDIT: Forgot about the no zeroes requirement. Added. But being on mobile now, can't check if still running OK.

Comment: It seems simpler but also slower than the one in the question. I am not sure if his implementation is broken and this is why it is faster though. :)

Comment: @Istvan: Considering `trunc_primes == []` at the end of OP's code... I can do a quicker implementation of that: `[]` :) `Prime.take_while {|p| p.between?(10,10000) }` is immediately `false`, so no looping actually occurs.

Comment: True! :) I like your implementation better, following the #1 principle of software engineering, don't reinvent hot water.

Comment: Ah.. I see I changed that logic(added `between?` instead of `p < 10000`) recently to test performance which actually broke the code. Thanks @Amadan Prime.each(10000) looks perfect. Awesome